# php compare variable does not work

Tags: php, bash

I have a litte php code which reads out a file which contains y or n or b.
I have echoed the file output and it displays perfectly y. Now if I compare the variable with y it does not accept it and proceeds with else.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID FROM review WHERE reviewer_ID='$reviewer_ID' AND products_ID='$products_ID'");
            if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 
            // this person has already reviewed it
            echo "you have already reviewed it<br />";
            echo "<p><a href=\"../page.php?productid=". $F_products_ID ."\">Zurück</a></p>";
    }else{

    // $out= y if its valid and $out= n if its a invalid review
    $out = shell_exec ("/home/script.sh $reviewlink");
    // time for the script to run. needs aprx. 1-2 seconds.
    sleep(2);
    // variables for PHP
    $valid = file_get_contents('/home/script/valid');
    $digits = file_get_contents('/home/script/digits');
    // PHP sends it to the DB if true

        if ($out == 'b' or $valid == 'b'){
        echo "<p>We have an issue right now!</a></p>";
        header('location:issue.php?productid=$F_products_ID');
        } else {
        echo "Review Status from file: $valid <br>";
        echo "Review Status from script: $out <br>";
        echo "Digits in Review: $digits <br><br>";
        if (($out == 'y' or $valid == 'y') and $digits >= $mindigits){
        //do stuff
```

So echoing out and valid displays y and the digits correctly, but comparing them with y (or with mindigits) seems not to work.
PHP thinks y =/y and i dont get it...

Comment: `$out == 'y' or $valid == 'y' and $digits >= $mindigits` is being evaluated as `$out == 'y' or ($valid == 'y' and $digits >= $mindigits)` when i suspect you want `($out == 'y' or $valid == 'y') and $digits >= $mindigits`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I fixed this one. But php still doesnt compare $out correctly with "y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `[0]` to the variables:

```
if ($out[0] == 'y' or $valid[0] == 'y'){ ... }
```

So only the first character is used for the comparing process.